# Buttons in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, button

I have created a 2d array of button to be drawn on program execution. What I would like is for each button clicked to correspond to another array I would create.

For example the button created at [3,3] would also refer to the other array at position [3,3].

Below is the code I used to generate the button array.

```
 Button[,] btn = new Button[12, 12];

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++)
            {
                btn[x, y] = new Button();
                btn[x, y].SetBounds(25 * x, 25 * y + 30, 25, 25);
                btn[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_Click);
                Controls.Add(btn[x, y]);
            }
        }

    }

    void btnEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: does it have to be done using a 2d array? I suggest making a struct of like buttons that contains 2 button properties. Then you can create a 1d array of those. Seems like it would be much easier to manage

Comment: This was the only way I knew of to generate the buttons on program launch. I could try something to the effect of what you have mentioned.

Comment: are both arrays of type button? if so i can undelete my answer because it would work. otherwise i misunderstood the question. thanks

Comment: Both types of array are not buttons. The button array refers to a simple array such as 'int[,] array = new int[12,12];' Sorry, I mustn't have explained my self enough. Thank you @Muckeypuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

**Make a new button**: 
Create a class

```
class CustomButton : Button 
{
     /* call all the base constructors and stuff */ 
     //Additional Properties
     int X { get; set; }
     int Y { get; set; }
}
```

which derives from a button and has extra properties for the coordinates in them. You can set these after the creation and then refer to them in the `btnEvent_Click` event.

```
CustomButton[,] btn = new CustomButton[12, 12];

public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++)
        {
            btn[x, y] = new CustomButton();
            btn[x, y].X = x;
            btn[x, y].Y = y;
            btn[x, y].SetBounds(25 * x, 25 * y + 30, 25, 25);
            btn[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_Click);
            Controls.Add(btn[x, y]);
        }
    }

}

void btnEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var button = sender as CustomButton;
     Debug.WriteLine("X: {0} Y: {1}", button.X, button.Y); 
}
```

**Or**: Find the reference to that button in the array again.

```
void btnEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var button = sender as Button;
     //Searching...
     int x,y;
     for(x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++) 
     {
         bool found = false;
         for(y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++) 
         {
            if(btn[x,y] == button )  {
                found = true;
                break;
            } 
         }
         if(found) break;
     }
     //Now x,y have the correct coordinates.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented the second solution you supplied. It works as intended now.